# Next Js - fetch and map multiple urls on Server Side Rendering

Tags: next.js, fetch-api, server-side-rendering, getstaticprops

Is there a way of fetching a list of urls in Next Js on the Server Side Rendering?

For example, the PokeApi has some info on the main url, but I need to render details that are inside of which unique url.

The unique urls (from 1 to 20 in the first page and goes on):

```
'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1'
'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/2'
'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1'
...
'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/20'
```

I tried with GetStaticProps, but I had no success.
With ForEach or Map, I can get the data show with console.log but I'm not able to map and render on the homepage.

The only way that it worked was with UseEffect, but it only renders on Client Side.

Thanks in advance